# openMP - Segmentation fault for dense matrices

Tags: c, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, openmp

I am implementing the [RCM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill%E2%80%93McKee_algorithm) in C trying to use openMP. In the loop where I gather the `neighbors` of a given `element` I am using two openMP directives as shown below:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(pos) private(i)
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(M[n*element+i]==1 && element!=i){
        #pragma omp critical
        neighbors[pos] = i;
        pos++;
    }
}
```

`n` is the dimension of the `n`x`n` sparse matrix `M`.

When I use a really sparse matrix (e.g. **density** = 0.1%) everything works fine, while when I increase the density of `M` to ~6% I get a Segmentation Fault error.

I have tried using `export OMP_STACKSIZE=1G`  in order to change the given openMP space but the problem remains. I have also used Valgrind but didn't provide any extra help. Is there some leak that I am missing in the given loop?

(*Sorry for not providing the whole code but it is really big. The reduction should provide all the info needed*)

Comment: What is `neighbors`? How much storage space does it have?

Comment: `neighbors` is an array with max dimension = `n`, because each `element` can have up to `n` neighbors

Comment: Is `pos` properly initialized to `0` before this loop? Does it work properly without the OpenMP directives?

Comment: Yes, it is initialized to `0` and everything is fine in sequential mode as well as in sparse matrices. The problem comes up in more dense matrices.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason for the segfault, but at least, the `critical` section should encompass both the assignment *and* the incrementation of `pos`. That means you need adding some curly brackets there... Now, I'm kind of skeptical the algorithm as you present it is correctly parallelized. The final content of `neighbors` will be subject to race conditions. Isn't that an issue?

Comment: You are right, both assignment and the incrementation of `pos` have to be in a critical section. I didn't know that curly brackets could define the section. Now segmentation fault is gone. Thank you so much guys.